# What is the right gradient to use to achieve the inner shadow effect of the native macOS graphical time picker with Flutter CustomPainter?

Tags: flutter, macos, gradient, flutter-desktop, flutter-custompainter

I'm recreating the graphical macOS time picker for [macos_ui](https://pub.dev/packages/macos_ui) and I'm having some difficulty painting the inner shadow gradient correctly. This shadow, along with the gradient of the clock's border, help give the clock a sort of 3D look.

Here is a screenshot of the native time picker:

[image]

As you can see, there is a shadow effect for the inner top half of the clock. It starts out white right around hour 9, then gets gradually darker and thicker as it reaches hour 12, and reverses back down to white at hour 3.

I've so far achieved the following:

[image]

As you can see, this is not correct. Here is the code I'm using to achieve this incorrect effect:

```dart
  void _paintInnerShadow(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint innerShadowPainter = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..shader = const LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
        end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        stops: [0.0, 0.5],
        colors: [
          MacosColor(0xFFA3A4A5),
          MacosColors.white,
        ],
      ).createShader(
        Rect.fromCircle(
          center: size.center(Offset.zero),
          radius: clockHeight / 2,
        ),
      )
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawCircle(
      size.center(Offset.zero),
      size.shortestSide / 2.0,
      innerShadowPainter,
    );
  }
```

What is the correct gradient I need to use to match the native look? I've experimented with Linear, Radial, and Sweep gradients and while I think LinearGradient is the right one, I haven't been able to work out the correct parameters for it.

Comment: You need `MaskFilter.blur`

Comment: @pskink I suppose that is somewhat closer to the original, but it's still not quite correct. I used `const MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 2.0)`.

Comment: Seems like using a `strokeWidth` of `2.0` and `const MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.inner, 1.0)` is even closer, but still not quite it.

Comment: Just played around with it and while it's interesting, and I appreciate you providing it, it doesn't seem to be what I need. Thank you again for your help, though!

Comment: i dont know how you used that but when i run the code i posted as a part of `CustomPainter` it casts shadows exactly like in the first image you posted - this is a normal way flutter draws shadws - for more see [_paintShadows](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/5464c5bac7/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/shape_decoration.dart#L355-L360)

Comment: this is how it looks like: https://pasteboard.co/qJ4V5AJq5gsQ.png

Comment: Well, for one thing, I had to remove the gray square around the green ring. Also, is the shadow painted as part of that green ring or is it separate? (the code you posted isn't available any more) And is the teal ring intended to approximate the silver ring around the clock?

Comment: Wow that actually looks like what I want, thank you so much!

Comment: That works even better, thank you!